# Aligning UIToolBar items

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitoolbar

I have three `UIBarButtonItem` created as below. They align left and I'd like to align center so there isn't a gap on the right side. I don't see an align property on `UIToolBar`. Is there another way to accomplish this?

```
//create some buttons
UIBarButtonItem *aboutButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"About" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showAbout:)];
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:settingsButton,deleteButton,aboutButton,nil]];
//Add the toolbar as a subview to the navigation controller.
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Add two UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace items to your toolbar, to the left and right of your items

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace, settingsButton,deleteButton,aboutButton, flexibleSpace, nil]];
```

Adding these as you would any other toolbar items will distribute space evenly between the two of them.

Comment: There's no real reason to make multiple flexible spaces. You can add the same multiple flexible space object to your toolbar multiple times if you need more than one.

Comment: mmc is correct.  In fact, it would probably be perfectly reasonable to make a singleton flexibleSpace and reuse it throughout your product.  I have heard it claimed that this was the true original use of singletons: not to enforce program rules, but to reduce overhead.

Comment: You forgot to update the release call, should read 
[flexibleSpace release];

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it read [flexibleSpaceLeft release] instead of [flexibleSpace release]. Typo fixed

Answer (score 32):

This can also be done right from a storyboard.

Just drag and drop items in the toolbar, and turn some of them into flexible or fixed space to get the desired effect. See the two examples below.

[image: Evenly spaced]

[image: Centered]

Answer (score 9):

In Xamarin iOS

Right aligned:

```
yourBar.SetItems(new [] { new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace), yourButton }, false);
```

Center Aligned:

```
var flexibleSpace = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace);
yourBar.SetItems(new [] { flexibleSpace, yourButton, flexibleSpace}, false);
```

Comment: This is not the topic. We are talking about pure iOS here.

Comment: Which is what MonoTouch targets.

Comment: Objective C question not MonoTouch/C#

Comment: @MaxMacLeod: it's not tagged obj-c, it's tagged iPhone. Therefore my answer is valid. It's also good to contrast c# vs obj-c. Clearly, c# is modern, slimmer, nicer, faster and superior in every way.

Comment: While it may have been clear that the code in the question was Objective-C, I found this answer helpful. It's a high ranking question in Google too.

Comment: Not a good answer for the primary question, but was helpful for me in working with Xamarin. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

**Swift version:**

```
    let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewController.view.frame.size.width, height: 35.0))
    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: viewController, action: nil)
    let button1 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "A", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.Plain, target: viewController, action: foo)
    let button2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "B", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.Plain, target: viewController, action: bar)
    let button3 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "C", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.Plain, target: viewController, action: blah)
    toolbar.items = [button1, flexibleSpace, button2, flexibleSpace, button3]
```