# problem to give colors for BarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, rightbarbuttonitem

i have a ToolBar in my view controller.i need to show one icon in right side of the ToolBar.
so i added a BarButton item and displayed icon image there.but the is a problem with icon color.it displaying as black which is not looking good and also cant able to arrange Barbutton items on right side of the Toolbar.can any one tell me a good way to do it.please help me to arrange barbuttonitems on right side and provide a way to give colors to BarButtonItem.

Answer (score 0):

Use below below change the color of `UIToolBar`.

**//Give your choice of color.**

```
  myToolbar.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
```

To align the right button you need to use a bar button of type `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` **Read SO post.**

[Aligning UIToolBar items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602717/aligning-uitoolbar-items)