# Align icons TabBar

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, tabbar

Well I have a problem,

I'm doing the reverse for my iPad app, but I want my tabbar is exactly like this:

[image: http://www.mediafire.com/?gi8arncjbjoehcf]

I'll put the volume controls, play and pause on the left and right side of the tabbar icons ....

how can I change the position of them?

Comment: Looks more like a `UIToolBar` actually.

Answer (score 0):

For alligning the elements, you should take a look at this question:
[Aligning UIToolBar items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602717/aligning-uitoolbar-items)

I'm not sure how to add custom controls to a `UIToolbar`, but I'd expect you could do this by setting their `frame` to overlap the `UIToolbar`.