# add button on UIToolBar (by code)

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

how do I add by code on a button to a toolbar that I have the property?

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolB;
```

Comment: can you explain a little more?

Comment: I want to code to decide whether to add a button to a view.
I thought about creating a "UIViewController" and put on a "UIToolBar" but I do not know how to add by code a button on the "UIToolBar" (positioned right).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem *buttonOne = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button One" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(action)];

UIBarButtonItem *buttonTwo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button Two" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(action)];

NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: buttonOne, buttonTwo, nil];
[toolBar setItems: buttons animated:NO];
```

Will do the trick if i understand correctly what you are asking. `action` being the method you want the buttons to call.

Comment: I have two questions:
1) if I added the "UIBarButtonItems" and "UILabel" from the storyboard, can I move them all right?
2) can I add "UILabel" into array?

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602717/aligning-uitoolbar-items

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, dont forget to release Buttons.

```
UIToolbar *actionToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 416, 320, 44)];
UIBarButtonItem *actionButton =
    [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
        initWithTitle:@"No Action"
        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
        target:self
        action:@selector(noAction:)]
    autorelease];
[actionToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:actionButton]];
```

UIToolbar dont have side buttons, you can use UINavigationBar or follow this link

[Aligning UIToolBar items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602717/aligning-uitoolbar-items)