# How to add a button on the right side of the toolbar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton

I created a toolbar programmatically:

```
UIToolbar *boolbar = [UIToolbar new];
    boolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    boolbar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [boolbar sizeToFit];
```

And then added a button to it:

```
UIBarButtonItem *cancelleftBarButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(tapBackGround:)];

cancelleftBarButton.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelleftBarButton, nil];
[boolbar setItems:array animated:YES];
```

However, this button appears only at the left side of the toolbar. Is it possible to put it on the right side of the toolbar ?

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here is the method to add the `UIBarButtonItem` on the right side of the toolbar.

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(btnItem1Pressed:)] autorelease];

UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil] autorelease];

UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(btnItem2Pressed:)] autorelease];
```

OR

If you are attempting to do it from the XIB , then .

Insert an item which has identifier being "flexible space".

[image]

Comment: Also check out these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602717/aligning-uitoolbar-items and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021138/how-to-adjust-uitoolbar-left-and-right-padding

Answer (score 6):

**In Swift**

```
let btn1 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button 1", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "btn1Pressed"
let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let btn2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button 2", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "btn2Pressed")
```