# Auto Layout with UINavigationBar and UIBarButtonItem

Tags: uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, autolayout

I like to create my views as standalone Xib files then instantiate them and add as subviews.

So, when working with a `UINavigationBar`, I expected to be able to do the same thing, first creating my custom view - from the Xib - then adding it as a custom view to the `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *anItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_myCustomView];
```

Then adding to the nav bar:

```
self.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[ anItem, anotherItem ];
```

So far so good.

Now, `_myCustomView` uses Auto Layout (AL) and I thought this would be no problem. *Not the case.* I've tried just about everything. Nothing has worked. I even tried adding the custom view as a subview of the controller that has the navigation bar. Thinking that as siblings in the view hierarchy, AL would treat it as a regular view outside the `UINavigationBar`.

That didn't work either. The controller's `updateViewConstraints` was called but never applied. The view's initial frame stayed at `CGRectZero`. It's as if AL sees that the view is on top of a `UINavigationBar`, even as a sibling, and decides it doesn't need laying out.

Of course, I've tried `bringSubviewToFront`, `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraintstranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, and so on. The latter gave the lovely:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still
>   required after executing -layoutSubviews. MyNavigationBar's
>   implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'

So, the question is, has anyone loaded a custom view with AL from a Xib, and successfully set this as a `customView` on a `UIBarButtonItem`? If so, how?

Comment: I have not actually filed a Radar for it yet, but I've run into this as well and it seems to be an iOS 6 bug. Creating the UIBarButtonItem and its view programmatically exhibits the same problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue ?

Comment: Any news on that topic? I think I still have a similar issue (albeit with a toolbar) in iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a duplicate of [iOS Autolayout and UIToolbar/UIBarButtonItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982302/ios-autolayout-and-uitoolbar-uibarbuttonitems)

`UIBarButtonItems` do not inherit from `UIView`, so using auto-layout based custom views within them might not be fully supported. Sounds like you have to do the pre auto layout thing until the issue is resolved. I would suggest filing a bug.

EDIT: By the pre auto layout thing, I mean manipulating the frame of your views directly.