# Autolayout inside UIBarButtonItem's custom view

Tags: ios, autolayout, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am having a strange problem with `UIBarButtonItem`. I am creating one with a custom view, and the view is of my own `MyCustomView` type. It contains couple of labels and some other subviews. Whenever I use autolayout in this custom view class to lay out the subviews - the button is displayed on top-left corner of the screen! You can see it in the picture below - `MyCustomView` just has one subview with gray background and I use autolayout to stretch it to fill the parent `MyCustomView`:

[image: wrong]

When I don't use autolayout everything is fine and the button is displayed normally:

[image: right]

Can anyone explain me what is going on here and am I allowed to use autolayout in custom views which are going to be put in `UIBarButtonItem`s (maybe not on the topmost level) ?

**UPDATE:** this happens after I do

```
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

in `MyCustomView` - in the top view which should be placed in bar button. I am doing it to make the system call my `intrinsicContentSize` method. I guess using the old `sizeThatFits:` instead would still be ok.

**UPDATE 2:** Here is the test code:

```
UIControl *cus = [[UIControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22)];
// uncomment the following line to mess everything
//cus.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
cus.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
label.text = @"Q";
[label sizeToFit];
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
[cus addSubview:label];
NSLayoutConstraint *centerX1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cus
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:label
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                           multiplier:1
                                                             constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *centerY1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cus
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:label
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                           multiplier:1
                                                             constant:0];
[cus addConstraints:@[centerX1, centerY1]];

UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:cus];
controller.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

I would be happy to get explanations to understand what is going on.

Comment: Why would you create a UIBarButtonItem with a subview ? Can you tell me the reason you need to do so indeed?

Comment: Because I need a complex widget on navigation bar, with several labels, states and animations between them. Why do you ask?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15651197/488611 It looks like auto layout can't be used in a UINavigationBar or UIToolbar.